# Testing Service insert duplicate "Name" expected thrown DuplicateException , but nothing was thrown

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I wrote a unit test in springboot, where when saving data with the same "Name" it will throw DuplicateException. However, when I tried to run it, the result was "Nothing was thrown".

my RoleServiceImplement.Class :

```
@Override
    public Role save(RoleDAO roleDAO) throws DuplicatException
    {

        Optional<Role> cekRole = roleRepository.findByName(roleDAO.getName());
        if(cekRole.isPresent()){
            throw  new RuntimeException("Already registered");
        }
        Date now = new Date();
        Role role = new Role();
        role.setCreatedBy(roleDAO.getCreatedBy());
        role.setModifiedBy(roleDAO.getModifiedBy());
        role.setStatus("1");
        role.setName(roleDAO.getName());
        role.setDescription(roleDAO.getDescription());
        role.setCreatedAt(now);
        role.setUpdatedAt(now);
        roleRepository.save(role);
        return role;
    }
```

My Unit test:

```
    @Mock
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private RoleServiceImplement roleService;

    @DisplayName("Duplicate Role")
    @Test
    public void duplicate_role_name_throw_errors() throws Exception{
      RoleDAO role1 = new RoleDAO();
      role1.setName("test");
      role1.setDescription("test");
      role1.setCreatedBy("test");
      role1.setModifiedBy("test");

      RoleDAO role2 = new RoleDAO();
      role2.setName("test");
      role2.setDescription("test");
      role2.setCreatedBy("test");
      role2.setModifiedBy("test");

      DuplicatException thrown = Assertions.assertThrows(DuplicatException.class, () -> {
        roleService.save(role1);
        roleService.save(role2);
        });
      }
```

Comment: Why should it throw an exception? You are using a mock, haven't registered anything on the mock so it will do the default, which is to return an empty optional. A mock doesn't magically know what to do you will have to register that yourself.